# How to install D-link DWA-131 B1 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, usb

Recently I built new PC with Ubuntu OS 14.04 (64bit). I noticed the D-Link Wireless N Nano USB Adapter doesn't get detected and installed automatically. The device is properly detected (listed in lsusb) but does not work out of the box

Following are the adapter specifications:
•Model No: DWA-131
•Hardware Version : B1

How to install this wireless adapter?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the `lsusb` output so that we can know the chipset it's using.

Comment: It must be rtl8192cu.

Comment: Sorry. Ubuntu correct version is 16.04 LTS. The output is  2001:330d D-Link Corp

Comment: see second answer - has a comment saying it worked for this specific device :)